# Returned Value always coming as undefined

Tags: react-native, expo

These are my 2 methods that I am having an issue with. I am trying to read a value from FireStore DB and return it to the other method but I am always getting undefined as my return value even though I am able to print the value as expected in the 2nd method. I tried increasing the timeouts as well. I probably cannot use useState() as I am calling the updateScore method from a different method in a if condition, so react hook rules error was being shown.

```
export function updateScore(username, Score, registerCallBack) {
    var s = getScore(username)
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("++++++++")
    console.log(s)           // Always undefined
    console.log("++++++++")
    firebase.firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(username)
    .update(
        {
            score: Score + s
        }
    )   
    }, 10000);
    
}

export function getScore(username) {
    console.log(username)
    firebase.firestore()
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(username)
    .get().then((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.data().score)  // PRINTING as Expected
            var score = doc.data().score;
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("-------")
                console.log(score)       // PRINTING as Expected
                console.log("-------")
                return score;
            }, 50);
        
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assign firestore function to a variable and return that variable.